# How to click on an image to show images with a function

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to click the magic8, but the happy, sad and surprised pictures won't show below the line. What did I do wrong? I have saved the images in random.js in the same folder.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type=text/javascript src="random.js">
        </script>
        <script>
        function magicEight() {
            var imgName;
            imgName = RandomOneOf(["happy.gif", "sad.gif", "surprised.gif"]);
            document.getElementById('outputDiv').value = imgName;
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <h1> Magic 8-ball (Mattel, Inc.) </h1>
            <p> Enter a question below, then click on the Magic 8-Ball to recieve its wisdom. </p>
            <input type="text" id="questionBox" size=90 value="">
            <p>
                <input type="image" src="http://balance3e.com/Images/8ball.gif" id="button" onclick="magicEight();">
            </p>
            <hr>
            <div id="outputDiv"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is `random.js`? Does the console log any errors?

Comment: and what is `RandomOneOf`?

Comment: Please post ALL of your code. It will help us answer your question. Thank you. Welcome to Stackoverflow  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show and image you need to add the value of the `randomoneof` on a img tag not on a div tag. Change that and I think it will work

Comment: how? so i shouldn't use outputDiv?

Comment: No, you should use:

    <img id="rand-image" src="path-to-the-image" />

And on javascript you should change the src value:
    document.getElementById('rand-image').src = "path-to-the-image";

Answer (score 0):

Setting `.value` on `outputDiv` will not display images. You have to set the `src` attribute of an `<img>` tag.

Assuming all of the random images live in `/Images`, you could use the below as your new magicEight function.

```
function magicEight() {
     var imgName;
     imgName = RandomOneOf(["happy.gif", "sad.gif", "surprised.gif"]);
     var imageTag = "<img src='/Images/" + imgName + "'>";
     document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML= imageTag;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I have to use RandomOneOf and each time when I click on the ball, it should shows up only one emotion.

Comment: @WinnieChan I've edited my answer. But if HienHuynh already answered your queation, accept his answer. (There should be a check mark somewhere to the left of his answer)

Answer (score 0):

Demo: https://codepen.io/hienhuynhtm/pen/dpLgNr

```
<script>
    var IMAGE_LIST = [
        "http://balance3e.com/Images/happy.gif",
        "http://balance3e.com/Images/sad.gif",
        "http://balance3e.com/Images/surprised.gif"
    ];
    function magicEight() {
        var imgName = IMAGE_LIST[Math.floor(Math.random() * IMAGE_LIST.length)];
        document.getElementById("randomImg").src = imgName;
    }
</script>

<div style="text-align:center">
    <h1> Magic 8-ball (Mattel, Inc.) </h1>
    <p> Enter a question below, then click on the Magic 8-Ball to recieve its wisdom. </p>
    <input type="text" id="questionBox" size=90 value="">

    <p><input type="image" src="http://balance3e.com/Images/8ball.gif" id="button" onclick="magicEight();"></p>

    <hr />
    <img id="randomImg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. Just make it clear what/where `randomImg` is for completeness.

Comment: @Terminus: I've just updated full code + Demo link. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @WinnieChan: my pleasure :)